# Potassium sulfate as a byproduct of manganese heptoxide synthesis?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Manganese heptoxide may be  formed by the action of concentrated sulfuric acid on potassium permanganate ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese_heptoxide)):

$$ \ce{2KMnO4 + 2H2SO4 -> Mn2O7 + H2O + 2KHSO4} $$

Could the amount of potassium permaganate as a reactant in the reaction be increased to yield potassium sulfate as a product instead of potassium bisulfate as shown?

Comment: Can you propose a chemical equation for that reaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reaction you mentioned shows the formation of manganese heptoxide and potassium bisulfate. But if you alter the stoichiometry of the reaction, i.e. change the moles of the reactant, you will obviously get different products like manganese(II or III)sulfate, manganese oxide, potasium sulfate etc. For this, the reaction conditions should be changed.

1. $$\ce{2KMnO4 + 2H2SO4 ⟶ Mn2O7 + H2O + 2KHSO4}$$

> Potassium permanganate react with sulfuric acid to produce
>   manganese(VII) oxide, potassium bisulfate and water. Potassium
>   permanganate - solid. Sulfuric acid - 98% solution. The reaction
>   proceeds at room temperature. Impurities: manganese(IV) oxide
>   $\ce{MnO2}$([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-1429))

2. $$\ce{2KMnO4 + H2SO4 → Mn2O7 + K2SO4 + H2O}$$

> Potassium permanganate react with sulfuric acid to produce
>   manganese(VII) oxide, potassium sulfate and water.([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-1899))

3. $$\ce{4KMnO4 + 6H2SO4 → 4MnSO4 + 2K2SO4 + 5O2 + 6H2O}$$

> Potassium permanganate react with sulfuric acid to produce
>   manganese(II) sulfate, potassium sulfate, oxygen and water. Sulfuric
>   acid - 60% solution. Impurities: ozone $\ce{O3}$.([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-6609))

4. $$\ce{2KMnO4 + 4H2SO4 ->[70-75°C] Mn2(SO4)3 + K2SO4 + 4H2O + 2O2}$$

> Potassium permanganate react with sulfuric acid to produce
>   manganese(III) sulfate, potassium sulfate, water and oxygen. Sulfuric
>   acid - 98% solution. This reaction takes place at a temperature of
>   70-75°C.([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-6610))